# VSTest step in Azure Devops not copying AutoMapper.dll´s

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am building a solution which has two referenced projects. One of the referenced projects is a test project. The test project has nuget´s and one of the nuget´s includes the automapper nuget as dependency. All the dlls are included in the test project and the automapper.dll and automapper.Net4 are set to copy local. When building it fails with the error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=3.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
```

If I look into the build server directory I can see that the automapper is missing. If I build the test project locally the automapper dll´s are copied to the output directory.

Any idea why the build server is not copying the automapper files?

Answer (score 1):

> VSTest step in Azure Devops not copying AutoMapper.dll´s

According to your description, you may not add the nuget restore task before you build your project, if yes, please try to add a `nuget installer` and `nuget restore` from Azure DevOps marketplace to your build pipeline:

[image]

If you have already added those two tasks, check the build log of those two tasks.

Hope this helps.